# Page Views before Event tracking

Tags: google-analytics

Is it possible to view the pages that a user has viewed before they have activated the event?

I have tried running custom reports but not sure if its the right thing to do or if I am even doing right.

Comment: Could you further describe what you have tried?

Comment: Hi there, of course. So I have attempted to run a custome report that includes the metrics - All events and Page Views and then a dimension of event category, action and label. But i would really like to look at what pages are looked at before this event occurs. If it is even possible to look